# {% if any([None]) %}show{% endif %} in template creates TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting a strange error. Putting `{% if any([None, 1]) %}show{% endif %}` in my Django template creates a TemplateSyntaxError.

Experimentation shows that `{% if True %}show{% endif %}` works so I know the problem is from `any([None, 1])`. I checked that `any([None, 1])` in python outside of Django and it returned True as expected so my code seems like it should work in the template. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for you time.

Comment: `any` is a python builtin. It is not available in django tamplates. If you want to do something like that, you can [write your own template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Django's templates are *deliberately* restricted not to make function calls with parameters, subscript, etc. These should be handled in the *view*, not in the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Your comment is what made the difference. I would give you the credit if you made an answer reflecting your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use proper boolean operators with `{% if %}` Django built-in:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators

Or write your own templatag as suggested by [Nafees Anwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4547481/nafees-anwar)